# How do I keep a MacBook battery charged to only 70%? (USB C connector)

Tags: macos, macbook, battery-life, charging

Following from this question and answer (https://superuser.com/a/1130375/979099) - Does anyone know the equivalent power cord trick for newer macs?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar answer, and it seems like there isn't a way just yet. You could provide a lower, steady input to match the usage using a lower power charger (see something like this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-gF8IC7x5k).

If you used a 5 watt charger from an iphone with a usb A -> usb c it will charge, albeit slowly.

Power while using the MacBook will come from the charger mainly, and any spikes over the 5w would come from the battery. Times where the MacBook is completely idle, the low wattage charger will trickle charge though, so it isn't a completely perfect situation.

Depending on your usage, you may also slowly lose battery charge if you're average use is more than the charger is providing (you could move up to a 12 watt iPad charger perhaps in this case).

Hopefully this helps you!